# jQuery $_GET Variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a modal window that uploads files to server. Works great. Upon completion of the upload I am refreshing a div on the parent page. Almost works. What I need in order for it to work is to be able to grab $_GET['edit']. Hopefully my layout of the code will help show my issue.

Modal Window: upload complete

```
$('#albumFinished').click(function() {
       $('#sortableImages').load('../includes/sortImages.php');
 });
```

sortImages.php

```
$galleryID = $_SESSION['newGalleryId'];
$getGalleryID = $_GET['edit']; 

echo "<ul>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       $sortImageName = $row['OrgImageName']; 
       $sortPath = "../data/gallery/" . $getGalleryID . "/images/album/" . $sortImageName;
                    echo "<li class='sortPhotos' id='recordsArray_{$row['id']}' >";
                    echo '<img src="'. $sortPath .'"/>';
                    echo "</li>";
                }

    echo "</ul>";
```

Everything is functioning properly except I am unable to grab the $_GET variable. How do I go about grabbing this variable? Also if my explanation is not clear, I will try to clarify further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry maybe I'm not understanding but your not actually sending any data to the sort images.php to get with $_get your simply doing a load which is identical to just typing that url in your browser

try using $.post or $.get or $.ajax to send your get info over similar to this

```
$.get("../includes/sortImages.php", { edit: "what your editing"},
   function(data){
     return your data here
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Clark. My chops are pretty weak when it comes to passing variables around. If i use 

$.get("../includes/sortImages.php",function(data){ });

my question would be how do I pull the $_GET['edit'] that I need from the URL? -- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `load` function include an extra param called `data`. This param is the one you have to use to pass parameters to the server via `GET`method. For example:

```
$('#albumFinished').click(function() {
       $('#sortableImages').load('../includes/sortImages.php',
       {newGalleryId: 'specify_an_id', edit: 'some_value'});
});
```

The third line pass the specified parameters and values to the server. Where you will be able to grab them